# How to match the specific time and date using regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am parsing through the log files which has each line starting with Date, time followed by system event message. I want to use regular expression to match the required date and time easily without the need for using strptime or any other time module to do the calculations. I have tried to match the date September 12 and specific time (9:23:45-09:23:50) i.e. logs for 5 seconds. The log file is in this format:

```
Sep 12 09:23:45 localhost systemd: Switching root.
Sep 12 09:23:45 localhost journal: Journal stopped
Sep 12 09:23:46 localhost journal: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 91.1M, trying to leave 136.7M free of 903.7M available ? current limit 91.1M).
Sep 12 09:23:46 localhost journal: Runtime journal is using 8.0M (max allowed 91.1M, trying to leave 136.7M free of 903.7M available ? current limit 91.1M).
Sep 12 09:23:46 localhost systemd-journald[88]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd).
```

The python code I have tried:

```
import fileinput,re
for i in fileinput.input():
    if (re.search(r'Sep 12 09:23:[45-50]',i)):
        print(i)
```

Also, can anyone tell me whats the impact of this same code if I am trying to parse through large file which is of more than 100 GB? Can I rewrite this code to reduce the overhead on memory?

Comment: Your regex won't match: `[45-50]` does not mean all numbers between 45 and 50. It means 4, or any number between 5 and 5 or 0. Something possible that would match is `Sep 12 09:23:(45|46|47|48|49|50)` but there must be some more clever solution. Also, you should ask your other question as another question, not two in the same (and check before if there isn't anything yet on SO about parsing large files with python).

Comment: This might be of interest too: http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with a slightly different regex:

```
^Sep 12 09:23:(?:4[5-9]|50)
```

Explanation: `[45-50]` is a character class that matches `4`, everything between `5` and `5`, and `0`. This is so because the character class is evaluated char-by-char. The classic fix for this is to define alternatives by number prefixes:

- `(?:...)` is a non-recording group for sparing some resources
- `4[5-9]` matches the numbers `45`, `46`, ... `49`
- the other alternative is `50`, the upper bound of your interval.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/CniWVd/1).

You can make sure to compile your regex only once. So your script uses less memory and CPU:

```
import fileinput,re
# this is the speedup
regex = re.compile('^Sep 12 09:23:(?:4[5-9]|50)')
for i in fileinput.input():
    # slightly different regex match call
    if (regex.match(i)):
        print(i)
```